# That/ it's inferred subject

Tags: british-english

That the human brain can use language is amazing.

What does 'that' represent when used alone in a statement perhaps.  E.g not referring to a previous sentence.

Does 'that' represent an inferred subject?

(In that sense is the comma correct in these dialogue examples or should it be a semi colon- technically).

That is true, don't you know.
It's true, don't you know.

Answer (score 1):

No, the word **that** does not imply an inferred subject.

- That the human brain can use language is amazing.

can be seen as a variant of the impersonal phrase: It is amazing

**It is amazing that the human brain can use language**.

**That the human brain can use language** is a noun clause used as a subject.

**Whereas**:
That is true, don't you know? is completely different.

That use of **that** is deictic (referential) and refers to a previous statement by someone. It is also the subject of the sentence

[Here's a useful explanation of deixis in English](https://www.thoughtco.com/deictic-expression-deixis-1690428)

The use of the comma is fine. **That's true, don't you know?** or: **It's true, you know?**

But you need a question mark there in a dialogue.

don't you know or you know are fine.

Comment: Could it be considered elliptical? '[The fact] that the human brain...' (I'm really no grammarian, though I am a native speaker, but sometimes using these things & being able to accurately describe them are two entirely different levels of linguistics ;)

Comment: Yes, we are all inclined to put in "the fact that" but it would not change the overall meaning or grammar. Then, the noun phrase just becomes longer. The noun clause would then be: The fact that the human brain can use language**||**is amazing. Of course, if you are a stickler re the grammar, you could describe it as: A noun + relative clause functioning as a subject.

Comment: in conversation, we use **that*** clauses in initial position more than one might initially think. If you are having a prolonged discussion with someone, haven't you found  yourself saying things like: "That he loves his wife is obvious to everyone" as a variant of: "It is obvious to everyone that he loves his wife."? :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That I use these constructions all the time without even thinking is, in itself, quite amazing;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Indeed. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, it's used to introduce old information (background knowledge). *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston, Pullum et al. (2002) says it "is by no means rare, but it is nevertheless much more usual for the content clause to occur in extraposed subject position, at the end of the matrix clause"; i.e., as *It's amazing **that I use these constructions all the time without even thinking**.* The part in bold has the form of a content clause, and functions as extraposed subject (not subject anymore), while the *it* at the beginning now takes on the role of subject.

Comment: That you think it is amazing is itself amazing.  :)

Comment: Any "impersonal" such as: It is [interesting, amazing, etc.] that [you think it necessary to quote grammarians] ***can be switched around to***: That [you think it necessary to quote grammarians] is [interesting, amazing, etc/]. Sometimes, it is important for a speaker or writer to emphasize an idea and not how it is qualified. Context is everything. What H, P et al. say is no different than what I said. It depends on what the speaker or writer is looking to emphasize. It's like a springboard. The first bit is the jump.